# Nested loops with time complexity log(log n)

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

Can there be an algorithm with two loops (nested) such that the overall time complexity is O(log(log n))

This arised after solving the following :

```
for(i=N; i>0; i=i/2){
  for(j=0; j<i; j++){
    print "hello world"
  }
}
```

The above code has time complexity of N. (Using concept of Geometric Progression). Can there exists similar loop with time complexity O(log(log n)) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a loop to iterate O(log log *n*) times, where the loop index variable counts up to *n*, then the index variable has to grow like the inverse function of log log *k* where *k* is the number of iterations; i.e. it has to grow like 2^2^*k*, or some other base than 2.

One way to achieve this is by starting at 2 and repeatedly squaring until you reach *n* - if the index variable is (((2^2)^2)...^2) with *k* squarings, then this equals 2^2^*k* as required:

```java
for(int i = 2; i < n; i = i*i) {
    //...
}
```

This loop iterates O(log log *n*) times, as required. If you absolutely must do it with nested loops, we can trivially add an extra loop which iterates O(1) times, leaving the total number of iterations asymptotically the same:

```java
for(int i = 2; i < n; i = i*i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```